# "There was a problem parsing the package" when installing my app

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I had to reinstall my computer. Now, when I'm launching my app from Eclipse on the virtual device, it works fine. However, when I create a distribution, *the .apk file is only half the size it used to be* so far and gives a

> "There was a problem parsing the package"

error message when trying to install the fresh .apk on my phone (Android version 4.1.2).

My manifest contains

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

I have the latest Android SDK tools etc. as well as API v8, v15 and v17 installed.
In "Project Build Target" (project properties), API 15 is checked. Lower than the one on my phone, so this common solution for this error message doesn't seem to apply in my case.

The distribution is using the default proguard-android-optimize.txt .

The fact that that the size of the .apk has halved made me suspect proguard, but even when I removed all options from its config file, the problem exists. I'm puzzled.

Comment: sorry for the odd title, but it isn't allowed to use the word "problem" in a title. I still wanted to mention the exact error message.